# codeigniter: how to edit a "value" form the data that existed at the html <select> tag bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have an edit form like this

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Drainase</label> 
<div class="col-md-7">
     <select name="drainase" class="form-control">
           <option value="" selected disabled style='display:none;'>Pilih Keadaan Drainase Lahan</option>
           <option value="3">Bagus; Cukup Bagus</option>
           <option value="2">Berlebihan; Buruk</option>
           <option value="1">Sangat Berlebihan; Sangat Buruk; Tergenang</option>
     </select>                                                
</div>
```

then I have a syntax that contains the value to be edited like this

`syntax a`

```
<?php echo form_input('drainase', $hasil->drainase); ?>
```

the `syntax a` has a value get from the database. we assume `syntax a` contains the value `3`. My problem here is how to keep **value** of `3` is entered in the edit form "drainase" and then in the form of "drainase", field automatically displays the selection of `"Bagus; Cukup Bagus"` because the value of `syntax a` has the value `3`?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `form_dropdown()` instead of form_input(), it will generate SELECT form element.

The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the **third parameter will contain the value you wish to be selected**

Check [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 2):

U should use form_drop down() instead of form_input().